# Limit Cloud Function to a domain without using balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a `Cloud Function` which i want to secure by allowing only access from *my* domain to *all users*. I am exploring this for days.

Google seems to limit many options and instead you are forced to buy and use more products, for example for this you need a `Network Balancer`, which is a great product but a monster to smaller businesses, and not everyone needs it (or wants to pay for it).

So, how do you secure a Function on the `Console`, without `IAM` (no signin needed), to only allow a certain domain calls before you expand to a Balancer ?

1. I do see that Google has something called `Organization policies for project` which supposed to restrict a domain, but the docs are not clear and outdated (indicate UI that doesn't exist)
2. I know that Firebase has the `Anonymous User`, which allow a `Function` to check a Google ID of an anonymous user, but everything online is a Firebase thing, and no explanation anywhere how to do this using normal Function with Python.

**EDIT**
I do use `Firebase Hosting`, but my Function is **Python** and it's handled from the GCP, not a Firebase Function.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, you can use `API Gateway`, with API `key`, ***restrict*** the key to your domain only, and upload a `config` with your `Function` url, so you access it with a API url+key, and nobody else can just run it.

See here [Cloud API Gateway doesn't allow with CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078178/cloud-api-gateway-doesnt-allow-with-cors/72078292#72078292)

I wish i could connect it to a domain as well, but we can't, google seems to want everyone to use the expensive Balancer, or Firebase (charged in this case on a Function use for every website visit)